# Symfony return empty form after validation with errors

Tags: forms, symfony

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   /** do stuff */
}
return $this->render('security/register.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView()
]);
```

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nickname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'asdasdasd',
            ])
            ->add('email', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Email',
            ])->add->add end more add }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            // the name of the hidden HTML field that stores the token
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
            // an arbitrary string used to generate the value of the token
            // using a different string for each form improves its security
            'csrf_token_id'   => 'registrationForm',
        ]);
    }
}
```

after wrong validation render an empty form

formType

this is a registrationtype class

what i can add to formType or to controller for returning filled input fields

Comment: As a start you can add constraints to your fields to make sure the correct values are filled in. That would prevent the form from submitting data and the page will not refresh and clear your inputs.

Comment: Are you using the twig form functions in your twig file?  What you have looks like it should work.  The csrf stuff you added is a bit unusual as csrf should be enabled by default.  But it should not impact the rendering.  I suppose you should verify that the expected values are actually being posted.

Comment: Cerad TY man? looks like a right way! my front end dev use native html fields like a
```<input name="registration_form[nickname]" placeholder="Нікнейм" class="form-control" required maxlength="10" autofocus autocomplete="off">```

Comment: usually one uses twig/form helper functions like `{{ form_start(form) }}{{ form_widget(form) }}{{ form_end(form) }}` (with optionally adding a submit button before form_end). `form_widget` will render form errors for the sub elements of your form.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing the comments under the question, it seems that the Twig part of the form is missing.

To render your form inside your Twig template, you should use [Twig form functions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#reference-form-twig-functions).

In your case you can simply write:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.nickname) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    {{ ... }}

    {{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'Submit me' }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

You also can use all form types that Symfony provides. For example, you can use for email field: [Email field type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/email.html).

```
->add('email', EmailType::class, [
    'label' => 'Email',
])
```

You can use many form field types, Twig can handle them: [form types](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html)